# Are the talks from TUG 2012 available online as videos?

Tags: tex-general

Are the talks from TUG 2012 available online as videos somewhere? Talks from TUG 2007 to 2011 can be watched at [River Valley TV](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/category/conferences/text/tex/), but I can't find anything from TUG 2012.

Are the 2012 talks online? If yes, where should I be looking?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

sadly, kaveh bazargan, who has in the past been the provider of video capabilities, was at the last minute unable to attend, so there is no video of the conference.

we're working on the proceedings as quickly as possible, but they will be only a pale substitute for seeing the speakers and their actual presentations.

sorry.

Comment: @barbara beeton: That's a shame. But we will be looking forward to the conference proceedings.

Comment: @Thorbjørn T: Thanks for the link to Frank Mittelbachs talk.

Comment: My talk was recorded with just some small digital cameras so don't expect too much and somewhere in the middle we had to change cameras because the card was full. It is now available at http://www.latex-project.org/papers/  --- there you also see the new logo for expl3 courtesy of @PauloCereda

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I will remove the dropbox link at some point so better remove your comment or point it to the official project site

Comment: Barbara if the proceedings are going to be so pale consider putting pictures of the speakers in ... I'm sure Alan made wonderful ones

Comment: I certainly would miss the video proceedings of TUG 2012. Any links of PDF slides of the authors would suffice